# Google Play Service Login Issue - SHA1 Fingerprint Issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

At present, I can't able to get log in within Google Play Services within my unity game.
I was getting this kind of message in the debug log:

[image]

I have checked all points, I don't find anything wrong within that apart from SHA1 fingerprint.
Because in the debug log, I was getting different and when I have created the Play Services app within the Play Store dashboard, it was different.
At app creation time, I got this kind of SHA1 fingerprint.

**SHA1 Fingerprint
6A:0B:64:BE:31:F1:5F:B0:E2:E4:C3:33:65:C7:31:6A:7B:A9:32:A7**

Now give me some direction to sign in within Google Play games services. I want to use this for leaderboard setup.

Answer (score 1):

I can able to sort out the problem my self so I am posting it here so that it becomes useful for other forum members and they can save their time and efforts.

**The main reason**, my KeyStore SHA1, and created Play Services App SHA1 was running different.

This document provides me a proper way to find the actual running problem.
[Troubleshooting Issues in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting)

For solution purpose, I have taken these two steps:

1. I have created new Client ID based on my KeyStore SHA1
   [image]
2. Link Play Service App with newly created Client ID so I have created a new link up for this purpose.
   [image]

After this, I run the same installed build of my Android phone and I can able to sign into Google Play Services account.